# Limit of definite integral with variable bound is equal to integral of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I'm working on a problem where the integrand is an unknown function of two variables. Based on the answer provided I know that the solution should be zero. I'm wondering if we assume something like $F^{\prime} (x,t) = f(x,t)$, then the following holds:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\int_x^b f(x,t)\ dt = \int_a^b \lim_{x\to a}f(x,t)\ dt.$$
An attempt at a proof for the above would proceed as:

Let $F^{\prime}(x,t)=f(x,t)$, then $$\lim_{x\to a}\int_x^b f(x,t)\ dt =\lim_{x\to a}[F(x,b)-F(x,x)]=F(a,b)-F(a,a)=\int_a^b f(a,t)\ dt=\lim_{x\to a}\int_x^b f(x,t)\ dt.$$

Is there a theorem or result that addresses the above, or something similar?

Comment: Oops! You should define what the prime means! Is it an $x$ derivative or $t$ derivative!

Comment: You didn't prove anything!